# Converting with yaml-cpp to a template class

Tags: c++, templates, yaml, specialization, yaml-cpp

I have my own container:

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer {}
```

And I'm using yaml-cpp for loading some data into this container.
So I need to write specialization for `convert` struct:

```
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<int> > {};
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<double> > {};
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<char> > {};
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<MyClass> > {};
```

... and so on.

Ultimately, I write:

```
// ...
node.as< MyContainer<int> >
// ...
```

But the fact is that every specialization for `MyContainer` is the same.
Therefore, every specialization for `convert` is the same and they are redundant:

```
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<int> > { /* the same code */ };
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<double> > { /* the same code */ };
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<char> > { /* the same code */ };
template<> struct convert< MyContainer<MyClass> > { /* the same code */ };
```

Is it possible to avoid this rubbish using c++ itself or some other features of yaml-cpp?

Comment: did you try a partial specialization like: `template<class T> struct convert< MyContainer<T> > { /*common code*/ };` ?

Comment: @piotr-s, no, i haven't. It seems to work. I skimmed through C++ book yesterday, but was unable to find this structure. Could you drop a line about how it works and give any links?

Comment: It is a partial specialization. Roughly speaking, any type matching the pattern (in that case, MyContainer<T>) uses that specialization.

Comment: @nirname Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @sehe, thanks. I've been reading 'Straustrup. C++ Programming Language. Special Edition'. Quite good book, but using templates are still not very clear for me.

Comment: @piotr-s, in fact the situation a bit more complex. What confused me, that `MyContainer` has two template arguments and `convert` has only one. So I should have written: `template<class A, class B> struct convert< Manager<A, B> > { /**/ };`. Sometimes templates' syntax is really vague.

Comment: @nimame It's not _vague_. It's _generic_. If you're learning C++, probably best to start with _concrete_ classes. And /use/ the generics from the standard library (so you know how they "feel")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the comment

> in fact the situation a bit more complex. What confused me, that MyContainer has two template arguments and convert has only one. So I should have written: `template<class A, class B> struct convert< Manager<A, B> > { /**/ };`

Try a variadic partial specialization

```
template <typename... Ts> 
struct convert< MyContainer<Ts...> > { 

    using container_type = MyContainer<Ts...>;

    // ... the specialized implementation, once

};
```

Comment: This very program is not c++11 program. But for 11th version it would be a solution.

Comment: Oh well: then indeed, fix it using the exact number of arguments required

Comment: For c++98: `template<class A, class B> struct convert< Manager<A, B> > { /**/ };`